# Alternativa php include para handlebars.js na construção de templates

Tags: php, javascript, handlebars.js

Estou fazendo um site novo, estou com o template pronto e quero implementar handlebars.js,

Para controlar o template sempre utilizei:

```
<php include "header.php"; ?>
<php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

e etc.

Quero melhorar o nivel dos meus projetos utilizando handlebars.js mas não sei como controlar o template com boas práticas. Acredito que criar um:

```
<script id="header" type="text/x-handlebars-template"></script>
```

e colocar todo meu header lá dentro com todas as tags e chamadas css não seria uma boa prática. Qual seria a melhor alternartiva para os includes?

Comment: Ou há muitas respostas possíveis ou boas respostas seriam muito longas para este formato. Acrescente detalhes para reduzir o conjunto de respostas ou isole uma questão que possa ser respondida em poucos parágrafos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ainda aguardo mais ideias mas a melhor solucao que encontrei por enquanto foi utilizar o Ember.js e sua estrutura de templates.
http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/the-application-template/

Fazendo um template com todo o header, footer e etc, dando include no body.
Estou achando uma boa alternativa por enquanto! Unico problema esta sendo manter todos os templates no mesmo arquivo html.